# Is it possible to add custom data to HealthKit?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios8, healthkit

We're making an app which collects a special type of data not supported by the list in the Health app. Is there a way to create a new category for this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, there isn't at this time. From the [HealthKit Framework Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/iOS/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HealthKit_Framework/index.html):

> The HealthKit framework is designed to share data between apps in a meaningful way. To that end, the framework constrains the types of data and units to a predefined list. These limits ensure that other apps understand both what the data means and how it can be used. **As a result, developers cannot create custom data types or units**. Instead, HealthKit attempts to provide a reasonably complete list of data types and units.

If I were you, I would file a Radar (http://bugreport.apple.com) detailing the type of health data you'd like to see added.

Comment: Is this still valid? I can't find it on the page you linked to anymore.

Comment: @pkyeck See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/saving_data_to_healthkit (looks like they moved it): "The quantity’s units must correspond to the allowable units described in the type identifier’s documentation."

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can. Just define it as an `NSDictionary` and pass it into the metadata field. Note the custom fields below: `push_ups`, `sit_ups`, and `status`.

```
let end = NSDate()
let start = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.CalendarUnitMinute,
    value: -2, toDate: end, options: nil)

let energyBurned = HKQuantity(unit: HKUnit.kilocalorieUnit(),
    doubleValue: 425.0)

let distance = HKQuantity(unit: HKUnit.mileUnit(),
    doubleValue: 0)

let status = "felt okay...could have done more"
let push_ups = 40
let sit_ups = 50

let s = ["push_ups": push_ups,
    "sit_ups": sit_ups,
    "notes": status
    ] as NSDictionary

// Provide summary information when creating the workout.
let wrkOut = HKWorkout(activityType: HKWorkoutActivityType.FunctionalStrengthTraining,
    startDate: start, endDate: end, duration: 0,
    totalEnergyBurned: energyBurned, totalDistance: distance, metadata: s as! [NSObject : AnyObject])
```

Comment: It's technically metadata - unlike other observation collection systems (with different extension mechanisms) metadata is not designed to store Codeable values. This may or may not matter.

Comment: So using this method is it also possible to store the data in the HealthStore and have it display in the apple Health app as a custom HKUnit on the graph?